# STP cable with BNC connectors?

Tags: bnc

Is there a cable-connector type on earth which is twisted shielded and uses BNC connectors as terminals? My data logging instrument has differential inputs with many BNC connectors. If I use an ordinary coax cable then it will not be twisted and pick up more noise, but if I want to use twisted then I cannot find a twisted shielded cable with BNC terminal. I need single pair twisted shielded cable with BNC terminals for each channel.

Does anyone have any experience with such issue?

Comment: Are you sure logging equipment uses differential inputs i.e. the housing of the BNC is insulated from other BNC housings on other inputs?

Comment: I would expect that **2** BNC ports would be needed to feed a differential signal to the instrument. OP: can you mention and/or include a link to the actual instrument you're using. You could consider using 2-wire shielded cable (like used for stereo-audio), assuming your signal frequencies are not very high.

Comment: There is such a thing as "[Twinax](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinaxial_cabling)", but I doubt that this would be compatible with the data logger.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The input connectors to the logger are same as in this photo: http://www.eagle.co.za/images/images_big/srl_bnc.jpg So it is calssic BNC inputs. So what you say is right(inner pin is HI outside pin is LOW so it is NOT single ended inputs). I thought about  using 2-wire shielded cable, but then I have to solder BNC connectors myself. My fear if I solder my self the result might introduce noise that's why in the market I was looking for a ready cable with its BNC connectors plus an extra shield. I dont wanna use typical BNC because it is not twisted.